# Linux command to "act" on new files in a specific folder?

Tags: linux, ftp, diff

I want to be able to ftp a file to a specific folder on a server and have that server run a script when it detects the new file. Any suggestions?

I tried some stuff with diff and a cron job every minute, but I couldn't quite get the results I wanted.

Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [inotify(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) facilities in Linux provide "[let me know me when this changes](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8478)" functions.

Comment: This got me to the correct place. I installed inotify-tools, which includes inotifywait. This looks like exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Just be a little careful that you wait until ftp has finished writing the file, and don't end up trying to process half a file....

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a good intro](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-inotify/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw07INotifydth-LX) on how exactly to do it. You'll need a C compiler and some basic programming skills. As msw said, it is based on the iNotify subsystem from the kernel, which enables a timely reaction on modifications to a directory tree.

Comment: Your link is very good also, at the time I posted mine, it was not there. So I thought to provide some value adding. +1 for your answer too :-)